# How can I change color of Status Bar background?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I scroll down `Status bar` across my text, and its seems terribly

[image]

Can I make a `status bar` background grey or dark and text of `status bar` light?

Comment: @LeoDabus  Duplicate questions to offer you the answer to the status bar text, it is, this is not change the background color to change color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style of the `status bar` can be changed to a `status bar` with white content. Go to the `ViewController.swift` file and add the following lines of code.

```swift
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

> enum UIStatusBarStyle : Int

- case `default :` A dark status bar, intended for use on light
  backgrounds.
- case `lightContent :` A light status bar, intended for use on dark
  backgrounds.
- case `darkContent :` A dark status bar, intended for use on light
  backgrounds.

If you want to change the background color of the status bar together, you can do the following:

```swift
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        view.addSubview(statusBarView)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        view.addSubview(statusBarView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add in your appDelegate this code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque
    return true
}
```

or in your info plist use

[image: info plist]

or in specific view

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
}
```

for view controller

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: This one changing Navigation Bar, I mean status of phone where battery status and other things

Comment: Still changing my Navigaton Bar view

Comment: well you don't specific what you are using, I updated my answer